# Get DISTINCT records on INNER JOIN SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, adhoc-queries

I have two tables. I have query that joins the first table to second table via `INNER JOIN` clause. The results show that there are redundant or duplicate results. In my example below the results have 4 records. I want to distinct the `SdiID` and I'm expecting to get only two records since there are only two unique records for `sdiID`. I tried adding on `DISTINCT sdiID` after the select but still I got 4 records. Please help. Here's my query.

```
    DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT, @RowspPage AS INT 
        SET @PageNumber = 1 
        SET @RowspPage = 20 
        SELECT totalCount = COUNT(*) OVER(), mailbox.ID as mailboxID, 
          sdi.ID as sdiID
           FROM [SDI].dbo.UserDocumentLocationOutbox mailbox 
           INNER JOIN [SDI].dbo.SDITransaction
           sdi on mailbox.SDITransactionID=sdi.ID 
         INNER JOIN [SYSDB].dbo.DocumentType doc on sdi.DocumentTypeID=doc.ID 
    where mailbox.CommunityID = '9ff10c7a-37f5-4580-9163-6ada55194ca7' 
    and mailbox.UserProfileID = 'f9791614-8cc0-42e3-87d1-53709bc1e099' 
    and doc.CommunityID = '9ff10c7a-37f5-4580-9163-6ada55194ca7' 
    and doc.Active=1 and doc.HideInMailbox=0  
    order by sdi.ProcessedDateTime desc 
OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage) ROWS FETCH NEXT @RowspPage ROWS ONLY
```

Here's the results

[image]

Comment: For each record pair of "duplicate" sdilD, there are two different mailboxIDs! How do you want this resolved? If you don't care about mailboxIDs, just use distinct but remove mailboxID from the select clause. Note that distinct goes to ALL fields and not only to the one that follows the distinct word. Another option is to put ALL the mailboxIDs in a comma seperated field, which has some work needed. Tell us what you need.

Comment: Distinct will work on complete row, and as you have different mailboxids for sdiID you are getting two-two rows for sdiID. Try after removing mailboxid from select and you will have two rows only.

Comment: Are you trying to count number of mailboxIDs for sdiID, or what are you counting?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Mailbox ids are not important. Below answer fits my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  with cte as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY sdi.ID order by sdi.ID) as rn,totalCount = COUNT(*) OVER(), mailbox.ID as mailboxID, 
          sdi.ID as sdiID
           FROM [SDI].dbo.UserDocumentLocationOutbox mailbox 
           INNER JOIN [SDI].dbo.SDITransaction
           sdi on mailbox.SDITransactionID=sdi.ID 
         INNER JOIN [SYSDB].dbo.DocumentType doc on sdi.DocumentTypeID=doc.ID 
    where mailbox.CommunityID = '9ff10c7a-37f5-4580-9163-6ada55194ca7' 
    and mailbox.UserProfileID = 'f9791614-8cc0-42e3-87d1-53709bc1e099' 
    and doc.CommunityID = '9ff10c7a-37f5-4580-9163-6ada55194ca7' 
    and doc.Active=1 and doc.HideInMailbox=0  
    order by sdi.ProcessedDateTime desc 
OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage) ROWS FETCH NEXT @RowspPage ROWS ONLY)
select totalCount, mailboxID, sdiID
from cte 
where rn < 2
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. By the way ";" is missing before the with clause. Thanks.

Comment: @JobertEnamno glad to help you =)

Answer (score 0):

You'll always get 4 results for this query as you have 4 different mailboxID values. I.E each of your sdiIDs has two MailboxIDs associated, so they are distinct records. You could remove one of these IDs for each by selecting the MAX(mailbox.id) as mailboxID or MIN(Mailbox.id) as mailboxID and group by ID?

Comment: it's a main point of the question: How to modify the query to get a described results